# Python Scrapy login authentication spider issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Folks, I have been trying to scrap few data from my websites. I am using python [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

However after going through the documentation everything looks good when I try with this HTML form on my website:

```
<form action="http://mywebsite.com/login/process" method="post">
    <div class="body bg-gray">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">                                                               
        <button type="submit" name="tempLoginProcess" value="" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">Sign me in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For this I am using the below PYTHON SCRAPY code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mywebsite.com'
    start_urls = ['http://mywebsite.com/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata = {
                'userid': 'admin',
                'password': 'admin',
            },
            callback = self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response): #check login succeed before going on
        dat = self.log(response.body)
        return dat
```

- Here above everything is working fine and result is coming as expected.

**NOW THE PROBLEM:**

I am again trying to login into some other account of my another website, it's form looks like the below (Which is quite complicated):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" html="{:onsubmit=>&quot;if($(this).valid()) $('input[type=\&quot;submit\&quot;]').attr('disabled','disabled');&quot;}" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
      <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Luvho/8odzEsVYhteyYtkwUhN0whT6nlFj4W4wth//s=">
  </div>

  <div align="center" class="alert-alert" style="margin-left: 10px;font-size:12px;color:red;">Email or password is incorrect. Please try again or click on Forgot Password</div>

  <div class="col-md-12 signupemail">
      <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email" size="30" type="email">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 signuppassword">
      <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password" size="30" type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 signupsubmit">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" id="">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

**This form is in a colorbox/ligtbox**

Now when I am trying it like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my2website.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.my2website.com/users/sign_in']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata = {
                'user': {
                    'email': 'fabdeal@my2website.com',
                    'password': 'my2website@123'
                }
            },
            callback = self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response): #check login succeed before going on
        dat = self.log(response.body)
        return dat
```

It's not going to the next page and still prints the sign in page only. Which definitely means that sign in didn't succeeded. Can you guys check and help me understand what's wrong.

**I am getting this as an end result:**

```
2015-12-04 03:02:21 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-12-04 03:02:21 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-04 03:02:21 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-04 03:02:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-12-04 03:02:23 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.my2website.com/users/sign_in> (referer: None)
2015-12-04 03:02:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.my2website.com/search_terms/search_for_user?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=&commit=&user=password&user=email> (referer: http://www.my2website.com/users/sign_in)
2015-12-04 03:02:26 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-04 03:02:26 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 899,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 40537,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 3, 21, 32, 26, 841202),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 3, 21, 32, 21, 846934)}
```

Let me know if any further information required.

**JUST FYI I am new to Scrapping and Scrapy**

** HERE is the website that I am unable to scrap** [ORIGINAL WEBSITE LINK](http://bit.ly/1OJYFGn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the value of the field `authenticity_token` in the login POST, this is a security measure. It's called Synchronizer Token, to prevent CSRF attacks, [read here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more info on the subject.

So your parse function should be:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # parse the security token
    token = response.css('input[name=authenticity_token]::attr(value)').extract_first()

    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata = {
            'user': {
                'email': 'fabdeal@my2website.com',
                'password': 'my2website@123'
                'authenticity_token': token
            }
        },
        callback = self.after_login
    )
```

Hope it works.